# Why is the equation number not coming in the same column in a double-column document?

Tags: equations, numbering

```
\begin{eqnarray}{\label{eq:9}}
    l(p_{ij}^d,\lambda,\mu,\delta)=\left \{\frac{1}{\text{ln}2} \sum_{j=1}^{M}\sum_{i\in \mathcal{D}_j} \text{ln} \left (1+\frac{p_{ij}^dg_{jj}}{\sigma_N^2+p_ch_{ij}}\right )\right\}\nonumber\\- \sum_{j=1}^{M} \sum_{i\in \mathcal{D}_j}\lambda_{ij} \left(p_{ij}^d-\frac{p_{c}g_{iB}}{(2^{R_{min}}-1) h_{jB}} + \frac{\sigma_N^2}{h_{jB}}\right)\nonumber\\-\sum_{j=1}^{M}\mu_{j}\left(\sum_{i\in \mathcal{D}_j} p_{ij}^d- P_{dmax}^j\right)\nonumber\\+\sum_{j=1}^{M}\sum_{i\in \mathcal{D}_j}\delta_{ij}p_{ij}^d
    \end{eqnarray}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX!  You shouldn't use `eqnarray` anyway: it gives bad spacing and has been deprecated for more than 20 years. Try with `align` from `amsmath`, which furthermore has a simpler syntax.

Comment: Please, post a minimal code so we could reproduce your margins and column width to help with format.

Comment: Also, you should use `\ln ` and `\min`.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to not using the [badly deprecated](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/196/5001) `eqnarray` environment, the following solution uses an `align` environment, uses `\biggl` and `\biggr` instead of `\left` and `\right` to size the large parentheses (resulting in both more consistent and more appropriate sizing), uses `\ln` instead of `\text{ln}` (for better spacing), and employs upright ("roman") lettering for "min" and "dmax". It also does away with the curly braces in the first row since they appear to be adding nothing but visual clutter.

With these adjustments, it's possible to make the equation occupy three rows rather than four.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'align' environment
\begin{document}

\begin{align}\label{eq:9}
l(&p_{ij}^d,\lambda,\mu,\delta)
    =\frac{1}{\ln2} \sum_{j=1}^{M} \sum_{i\in\mathcal{D}_j} 
    \ln \biggl( 1+\frac{p_{ij}^d g^{}_{jj}}{\sigma_N^2+p_c h_{ij}} \biggr) \nonumber\\
    &- \sum_{j=1}^{M} \sum_{i\in\mathcal{D}_j}\lambda_{ij} 
    \biggl( p_{ij}^d-\frac{p_{c}g_{iB}}{(2^{R_{\min}}-1) h_{jB}} 
    + \frac{\sigma_N^2}{h_{jB}} \biggr)\nonumber\\
    &-\sum_{j=1}^{M}\mu_{j} \biggl(\,\sum_{i\in\mathcal{D}_j} p_{ij}^d
    - P_{\mathrm{dmax}}^j \!\biggr)%\nonumber\\
    +\sum_{j=1}^{M}\sum_{i\in\mathcal{D}_j}\delta^{}_{ij}p_{ij}^d
\end{align} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: It should be `l(p_{ij}^d,{}&\lambda,\mu,\delta)` to get correct spacing after the first comma. Maybe `l(p_{ij}^d&,\lambda,\mu,\delta)` or even `l(&p_{ij}^d,\lambda,\mu,\delta)`

Comment: @egreg - Many thanks for these suggestions! I've implemented them; and I've taken the opportunity to tweak the subscript placements of `g_{jj}` and `\delta_{ij}` in the first and third rows, resp.

Answer (score 5):

Here a code for an equation fitting the column width, with some manual spacing adjustments:

```
\documentclass[ a4paper, twocolumn]{article}%
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{mathtools, nccmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
   \begin{fleqn}
      \begin{equation}
        \label{eq:9}
        \begin{aligned}[b]
           & l(p_{ij}^d,\lambda,\mu,\delta )= \\
           & \mkern-4mu -\!\biggl\{\frac{1}{\ln 2} \sum_{j=1}^{M}\sum_{i\in \mathcal{D}_j} \ln\biggl(1\!+\!\frac{p_{ij}^dg_{jj}}{\sigma_N^2+p_ch_{ij}}\biggr) \biggr\}
          \\&\mkern-4mu -\!\sum_{j=1}^{M} \sum_{i\in\mathcal{D}_j}\mkern-5mu \mathrlap{\lambda_{ij}\biggl(p_{ij}^d\!-\!\frac{p_{c}g_{iB}}{(2^{R_{\min}}\!-\!1) h_{jB}}\!+\!\frac{\sigma_N^2}{h_{jB}}\!\biggr)}\\%
           & \mkern-4mu -\!\sum_{j=1}^{M}\mu_{j}\biggl(\sum_{i\in \mathcal{D}_j}\! p_{ij}^d\!-\! P_{d\max}^j\!\biggr)\!+\!\sum_{j=1}^{M}\!\sum_{i\in \mathcal{D}_j}\!\delta_{ij}p_{ij}^d
        \end{aligned}
      \end{equation}
    \end{fleqn}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}​
```

[image]

If you accept that part of the equation be medium size (~80% of `\displaystyle`), the `\medmath` command from `nccmath` allows for a simpler code, without manual adjustment:

```
\begin{fleqn}
  \begin{equation}
    \label{eq:9}
    \begin{aligned}[b]
       & l(p_{ij}^d,\lambda,\mu,\delta )= \\
       & \medmath{\biggl\{\frac{1}{\ln 2} \sum_{j=1}^{M}\sum_{i \in \mathcal{D}_j} \ln\biggl (1+\frac{p_{ij}^dg_{jj}}{\sigma_N^2+p_ch_{ij}}\biggr ) \biggr\}} \\[-1ex]
      &\medmath{-\sum_{j=1}^{M} \sum_{i \in \mathcal{D}_j}\lambda_{ij} \biggl(p_{ij}^d-\frac{p_{c}g_{iB}}{(2^{R_{\min}}\!-\!1) h_{jB}} + \frac{\sigma_N^2}{h_{jB}}\biggr)} \\[-1ex]%
       &\medmath{-\sum_{j=1}^{M}\mu_{j}\biggl(\sum_{i \in \mathcal{D}_j} p_{ij}^d - P_{d\max}^j\biggr) +\sum_{j=1}^{M}\sum_{i \in \mathcal{D}_j}\delta_{ij}p_{ij}^d}
    \end{aligned}
  \end{equation}
\end{fleqn}
```

[image]

Comment: @Mico: Yes, I've just seen the (now fixed) problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

solution with use of `\MoveEqLeft` from `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} % for '\MoveEqLeft' com.
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{align}\label{eq:9}
\MoveEqLeft
l(p_{ij}^d,\lambda,\mu,\delta)  \notag\\
    & = \frac{1}{\ln 2} \sum_{j=1}^{M}\sum_{i\in\mathcal{D}_j}
        \ln \biggl( 1+\frac{p_{ij}^d g_{jj}}{\sigma_N^2+p_c h_{ij}} \biggr) \notag\\
    & - \sum_{j=1}^{M} \sum_{i\in\mathcal{D}_j}\lambda_{ij}
        \biggl( p_{ij}^d-\frac{p_{c}g_{iB}}{(2^{R_{\min}}-1) h_{jB}}
      + \frac{\sigma_N^2}{h_{jB}} \biggr)\notag\\
    & - \sum_{j=1}^{M}\mu_{j} \biggl(\,\sum_{i\in\mathcal{D}_j} p_{ij}^d
      - P_{d\max}^j \biggr)\notag\\
    & + \sum_{j=1}^{M}\sum_{i\in\mathcal{D}_j}\delta_{ij}p_{ij}^d
\end{align}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]

**addendum:**
with use `\medmath` from `nccmat` package this formula can be fit in four rows:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}  % for '\MoveEqLeft' command
\usepackage{nccmath}    % for medium size of equation
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{equation}
\medmath{\begin{aligned}[b]\label{eq:9}
\MoveEqLeft
l(p_{ij}^d,\lambda,\mu,\delta)                                              \\
    & = \frac{1}{\ln 2} \sum_{j=1}^{M}\sum_{i\in\mathcal{D}_j}
        \ln \biggl( 1+\frac{p_{ij}^d g_{jj}}{\sigma_N^2+p_c h_{ij}} \biggr) \\
    & - \sum_{j=1}^{M} \sum_{i\in\mathcal{D}_j}\lambda_{ij}
        \biggl( p_{ij}^d-\frac{p_{c}g_{iB}}{(2^{R_{\min}}-1) h_{jB}}
      + \frac{\sigma_N^2}{h_{jB}} \biggr)                                   \\
    & - \sum_{j=1}^{M}\mu_{j} \biggl(\,\sum_{i\in\mathcal{D}_j} p_{ij}^d
      - P_{d\max}^j \biggr) + \sum_{j=1}^{M}\sum_{i\in\mathcal{D}_j}\delta_{ij}p_{ij}^d
\end{aligned}
}
\end{equation}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]